# Jquery form plugin on IE7

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

I tried using jquery form plugin on IE7. I wanted to use this specifically http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html . When I tried it over Chrome/FF it worked. But with IE, it didn't work. I tried changing the form method to GET and it worked on IE. Is there a way I can use the plugin with POST ?

Thanks, 
Anush

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you're code is trying to do?

Comment: Here is the code - http://pastebin.ca/1906449

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ask the developer of the plugin as he force the method to "POST" around jquery.form.js:238.